# Javascript function updating the wrong field

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using a javascript function to concatenate two fields FirstName and LastName into one single field FullNameText.

This is the javascript function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function loadFullName()
        {

            var lblFullNametext = document.getElementById('MainContent_frmAuthor_lblFullNameText');
            var txtAuthor_FirstName =   document.getElementById('<% = frmAuthor.FindControl("txtAuthor_FirstName").ClientID %>');
            var txtAuthor_LastName = document.getElementById('<% = frmAuthor.FindControl("txtAuthor_LastName").ClientID %>');
            var comma = "";
            if (txtAuthor_FirstName.value != "" || txtAuthor_LastName.value != "")
            {
                comma = ", ";
            }
            document.getElementById('MainContent_frmAuthor_lblFullNameText').textContent = txtAuthor_LastName.value + comma + txtAuthor_FirstName.value;


        }


    </script>
```

And this is my aspx code within a FormView:

```
    <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                         <tr>
                            <td>ID</td>
                            <td >
                                <asp:Label ID

="txtAuthor_ID" runat="Server" Text="(New)" Width="50%" />
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFullName" Text="Full Name" >Full Name</asp:Label>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFullNameText" ></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name <span style="color:red">*</span></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAuthor_FirstName" runat="Server" onkeyup="loadFullName();"
                                />
                        </td>
                         <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAuthor_LastName" runat="Server" onkeyup="loadFullName();"
                                />
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </table>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
```

When I click a button Save in my FormView with both FirstName and LastName blank, the lblFullName field get replace by a comma, while the lblFullNameText remains blank.

I'm certainly missing something here but I can't get my head around it.

1) Why is the LoadFullName() being triggered while I haven't pressed any keys on the FirstName and LastName textboxes? There are also no references to that function in my code.

2) Why is the lblFullName label being replace with a "comma" although the label that is supposed to change is lblFullNameText ?

I would appreciate if someone can point me to the mistake I'm doing. Please let me know if I should provide any more information.